# Expectation and Standard deviation of lifetime of a bulb with uniform probability distribution

Tags: probability, continuity

I came across a problem in the book "Understanding Probability" in the section on uniform continuous variables:

> The lifetime of a light bulb has an uniform probability density
> on (2, 12). The light bulb will be replaced upon failure or upon reaching the age 10, whichever occurs first. What are the expected value and the standard deviation of the age of the light bulb at the time of replacement?

I saw a possible explanation at [A doubt in finding the expected value of lifetime](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3166995/a-doubt-in-finding-the-expected-value-of-lifetime) but I still don't get it.

I applied the formula for expectation $E(X) = \frac{a + b}{2}$ to get 7, and for variance to get $\sigma = \sqrt \frac {(b - a)^2}{12}$ to get 2.88, but apparently the correct answers are 6.8 and 2.613 respectively. I just can't  wrap my mind around it. I tried "relocating" the distribution to (0,10) but it still doesn't work!

Can anyone help me here? Thanks!

Comment: $$\int_2^{10}\frac x{12-2}dx+\int_{10}^{12}\frac {10}{12-2}dx=6.8$$

Comment: $$\int_2^{10}\dfrac {x^2}{12-2}dx+\int_{10}^{12}\dfrac {10^2}{12-2}dx-6.8^2\approx2.613^2$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error  you did is to confuse the Uniform distribution of the bulb lifetime with its actual lifetime...if the lifetime is $X>10$ they substitute the bulb thus its lifetime remains 10.

Formally, the lifetime duration is represented by the following "mixed" density

$$d(x)=\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{10},  & \text{if $2\leq x<10$} \\
\frac{2}{10},  & \text{if $x=10$}\\
0,  & \text{elsewhere}
\end{cases}$$

Thus, as already written,

$$\mathbb{E}[X]=\int_2^{10}\frac{x}{10}dx+10\frac{2}{10}=6.8$$

$$\mathbb{E}[X^2]=\int_2^{10}\frac{x^2}{10}dx+10^2\frac{2}{10}=\frac{496}{15}+20$$

that is

$$\mathbb{V}[X]=\mathbb{E}[X^2]-\mathbb{E}^2[X]$$

Comment: Okay, it makes a bit more sense now. I'm understanding it like this: when the bulb is replaced, its lifetime must have been at most 10. If it were replaced due to failure, its lifetime must have been between 2 and 9 inclusive (continuous part). Else it must have been equal to 10 (discrete part). Then you added up the respective expectations, right?

Comment: @Tasneem Noor Mohamed : right. Observe that the continuous part is $[2;10)$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $L$ be the lifetime of the bulb. What you are asked to find are the mean and the standard deviation  of the random variable $X=\min \{L, 10\}$. This random variable does not have density. The reason is $X=10$  iff $L >10$ so $P(X=10)=P(L >10)=\frac {12-10} {12-2}=\frac  2 {10}=0.2$. For $2<x <10$ we have $P(X<10)=P(L<10)=\frac {x-2} {12-2}$. Thus the distributon jis  amxituer of a cnsta and  discerte distribution.. You can  find the mean as follows: $EX=\int_2^{10} x \frac d {dx} (\frac {x-2} {12-2})dx+10P(L=10)$ and this works out to $6.8.$ I will let you compute $EX^{2}$ in a similar way and find the standard deviation.